# SQL Server 2008 R2 Slow Query Performance

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008

I have a query with 2 parameters, 4 left joins, and an ORDER BY. Recently this query and others began to take a long time (20sec to 2 ½ min) to complete.

Based on some posts about slow responses I did the following:

- Ran `SP_UPDATESTATS` – no noticeable effect
- Added `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` - no noticeable effect
- Made sure the parameter data types and the database data types matched – they do.

On my own I decided to create indexes on all table columns that were used in the query as parameters, compares, joins, or in the order by. Creating the indexes significantly improved the query speed (1sec) for a few minutes.

After much experimentation in Management Studio I have found that the complexity of the query does not seem to matter much, I removed all the LEFT JOINS and got a fast response (<1sec), and then I added them back in one at a time until it slowed (on the 3rd one). I indexed the columns in the LEFT JOIN table and got fast times so I thought I was onto something, but after a few minutes back to 26 secs.  I re-added the joins and sometimes the query is fast and sometimes slow – all with identical parameters, just running the same query over and over again, a few seconds apart.  Generally it seems after I made a change (adding an index or removing a JOIN) it would be very fast, then a minute later I would run it and it would take 26 secs again.

In the end I can find no logical relationship between any changes I made to the query or indexes I added and speed.

So my conclusion is it is not indexing or query complexity (although in general simpler queries did run a bit faster).

Looking at the Activity Monitor is Mgmt Studio there is a panel labeled Recent Expensive Queries.  When I run the 26 sec query it shows up there with some statistics I don’t fully understand.

As of now the query below is returning almost instantly, whereas 15 minutes ago it took 26 sec. I'm at a loss a to why.

The database has only a few active users, the clients table size is a few thousand records.  The server CPU % is always very low. The box it’s running on is a VPS (virtual private server) but sql server is the only major process running on my portion of it and the box seems quite responsive when I log in.  Memory is 4GB and most of that is used up.

For some context, here is the original query I've been working with:

```
DECLARE @SN char(6)
DECLARE @Type int

SET @SN='LA2007'
SET @Type = 1

SELECT TOP 50 
    -4 AS tz, c.ID, c.Type, c.Name, c.DBAName, c.ContactName,
    c.Addr1, c.Addr2, c.City, c.State, c.Zip, c.Zip4, 
    c.Email, c.Phone, c.Phone2, c.Phone3, c.FAX, c.WWW, 
    c.LastActivityOn, c.Description, c.IDNumber, ci.Prospect, 
    pi.Username, loc.LocationName AS xLocation,
    lao.Name AS xLastActivityBy
FROM 
    Clients c
LEFT JOIN 
    CustomerInfo ci ON ci.ClientID = c.ID
LEFT JOIN 
    ProducerInfo pi ON pi.ProducerID = ci.CSR
LEFT JOIN 
    Locations loc ON loc.ID = c.LocationID
LEFT JOIN 
    Clients lao ON lao.ID = c.LastActivityBy
WHERE 
    c.SN = @SN AND c.Type = @Type
ORDER BY 
    c.LastActivityOn DESC, c.Name
--OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)
```

Comment: Search for sql server parameter sniffing,quick way to test it add `option recompile`

Comment: Post the execution plan. Try to provoke a slow run of the query and run Adam Machanics sp_whoisactive. It shows you what the query is waiting for at the moment. Does it show IO or locks as the wait reason?

Comment: Are those **foreign key columns** in your JOIN's all properly indexed?

Comment: When it is slow look for any locking on the tables from other transactions. Are any updates happening in other sessions? take a look at sp_locks

Comment: that sounds like something going on with the execution plan. Could you try and execute your sproc with 'WITH RECOMPILE'? Reason I think it's the exec plan: Everything you changed that got you short performance boosts would force the sql server to recompile the exec plan for that sproc.

Comment: marc_s - yes all are indexed, the ones named 'ID' are primary keys, the others I have created indexes for.  But I had removed all joins and it was still slow (sometimes).

Comment: http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2007/11/27/parameter-sniffing/

Comment: UPDATE - Good I suppose but I can't get it to run slow now. Param sniffing is interesting but this query is not a SP. I did find a missing index on a different query thanks to a hint in the execution plan.  Will post EP if it slows.

Comment: See [link](http://tinyurl.com/otde9sp) - took 31 sec this morning, yesterday <1sec, no changes were made. Query same as above.

Comment: This [article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/258/eliminating-bookmark-keyrid-lookups/) helped me understand how to remove Key Lookups with a covering index. My server RAM was maxed out, a reboot improved performance.  Also I think I need to re-design my queries to be a bit more thoughtful about what really needs to be returned.